# Is a Brownian motion non-stationary?

Tags: normal-distribution, stationarity

This [Wiki-Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Covariance_functions) quotes

```
  "a Brownian motion process, is non-stationary"
```

I dont see why this is the case? A [stationary process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) means that the distribution of any substring is constant, which is satisfied by a Brownian Motion obviously.

Comment: Note, however, that the increments of the Brownian motion $(W_t - W_s)_t$ are stationary.

Answer (score 6):

Brownian motion is indeed not stationary (for the definition of stationary of you cite, or any that I know ).

The distribution at time $t$ is Normal with variance $t$.  Thus it changes with time, and not stationary.

Comment: Consider the definition of stationarity: $F_{X}(x_{t_1+\tau} ,\ldots, x_{t_k+\tau}) = F_{X}(x_{t_1},\ldots, x_{t_k})$. It does not mean that the distribution cannot change with time, it is only for a substring interval, or how am I'm wrong?

Comment: What does $k=1$ and $t_1=0$ in your definition of stationary mean?

Comment: Please see the second Wikipedia link in the question for details.

Comment: Yes **I** know what they mean.  Look, the special case of your definition that I alluded to is $F_X(x_\tau) = F_X(x_0)$.  Can **you** see what this says and why it is relevant to your question?  To be explicit, the distribution at any given time is the same as time 0.

Comment: A quote from the first paragraph of the wikipedia article you link to: "Consequently, parameters such as the mean and variance, if they are present, also do not change over time"

Comment: I grant it that the wikipedia notation is shockingly bad! :)

Comment: Thanks for your example: $x_\tau$ and $x_0$ are both Brownian motions and I agree that $x_\tau$ has a higher variance though. Maybe can you also comment on why on the other hand, the increments of Brownian motion are stationary? I assume this is only under a fixed incremental interval?

Comment: I think there are multiple versions of stationarity floating around. Often stationarity means some *conditional* staitonarity not *unconditional* stationarity. I *think* the unconditional is stationarty? I think it would be helpful to update to include the speicfic definition and never leave out conditioning on intial condition if that is what you are doing.